# Multiple class Get each value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I get value of textbox appended with image tag. There is list of images with class="hi" and textbox with class multiple.

```
<div id="images">
    <img src="www.xyz.com/qwert.jpg" class="hi">
    <input type="text" class="multiple">
    <img src="www.xyz.com/qwerty.jpg" class="hi">
    <input type="text" class="multiple">
    <img src="www.xyz.com/qwertww.jpg" class="hi">
    <input type="text" class="multiple">
</div>
```

How can I get src and value of textbox ?

Script I tried:

```
var values = "";                    
$(".hi, .multiple").each(function () {                  
    imageURI = $(this).attr('src'); // I am getting imageURI
   ????                             //How can I get texbox value? 
 });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$(".hi").each(function () {                  
    var imageURI = $(this).attr('src'); 
    var textBoxVal = $(this).next().val(); 
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(".hi").each(function () {                  
    var imageURI = $(this).attr('src'); 
    var textBoxVal = $(this).next('input').val(); 
 });
```

Comment: `Closest('input')` will target a parent input, not a sibling one

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var values = "";                    
$(".hi, .multiple").each(function () {                  
    imageURI = $(this).attr('src'); // I am getting imageURI
    textBoxVal =  $(this).val();
 });)
```